# My sprite images is not showing?

Tags: css, css-sprites

This is my code, simply, I want to center the slider. But Images are not showing and I am very sure the location[image reference] is proper. So what is wrong with my code? Help me?

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slider {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider#img1 {
    background: url('../images/all-images-sprite.png') no-repeat  0 -1368px;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
.slider#img2 {
    background: url('../images/all-images-sprite.png') no-repeat  0 -1740px;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
.slider#img3 {
    background: url('../images/all-images-sprite.png') no-repeat  0 -1568px;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
.slider#img4 {
    background: url('../images/all-images-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 -967px;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

this is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/rdjajvuh/)

Comment: please provide working fiddle or code pen live URL,so it easy to understand.

Comment: please add specific height to it if there is nothing in div

Comment: Why are you using `background-size: cover;`? It will cause problems with using sprites.

Comment: @Mr_vasu this is my fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/rdjajvuh/

Comment: @Toby please see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/rdjajvuh/

Comment: There's a few problems here.. you're setting `height: 30%` on `.slider` but it's height is actually 0. You're using `.slider#img1` instead of `.slider #img1` to correctly target the children of `.slider`. There's too much to fix everything, but update with these issues resolved and we can try further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to keep the ratio you need to size width and height.

from your fiddle we can start from html (window's size).

Your mistakes: `width:50%` and then `300px`. and then `height:auto` which is **null** when container is **empty**.
also, the selector to use is `.slider #id` where `#id` is a child

so the example :) https://jsfiddle.net/rdjajvuh/3/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slider {
  width: 50%;
  height: 33vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid;
}
/* demo test purpose*/
.slider>div {/* see me */
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px ;
  }
.slider #img1 {
  background: url('https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider #img2 {
  background: url('https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png') no-repeat 0 12%;/* % because size is 50%x33vw ... */
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider #img3 {
  background: url('https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png') no-repeat 0 23%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider #img4 {
  background: url('https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png') no-repeat 0 33.65%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div id="img1"></div>
  <div id="img2"></div>
  <div id="img3"></div>
  <div id="img4"></div>
</div>

<a href="#">Previous</a>
<a href="#">Next</a>
```

for background-position since image can be any size, you can use % (run snippet in full page mode to see why). tune it to your needs

Comment: is there any other way to solve pixelation? my images was hd but it's pixelated?

Comment: @learningjavascriptks you need to start with a bigger higher resolution  image :(

Comment: lastly, i don't understand vw and this -> 0 12%;/* % because size is 50%x33vw ... */. how did you calculate percentage and vw?

Comment: It is because size is not fixed pixels, but about window's width.

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet

```css
.sprite {
  display: block;
}
.imgs {
  width: 120px;
  height: 76px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#img1 {
  background-position: -5px -5px;
  background-image: url(https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png);
}
#img2 {
  background-position: -5px -84px;
  background-image: url(https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png);
}
#img3 {
  background-position: -5px -165px;
  background-image: url(https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png);
}
#img4 {
  background-position: -5px -245px;
  background-image: url(https://s32.postimg.org/ge685yjyt/all_images_sprite.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite">
  <div id="img1" class="imgs"></div>
  <div id="img2" class="imgs"></div>
  <div id="img3" class="imgs"></div>
  <div id="img4" class="imgs"></div>
</div>
```